# How to iterate over CUDA-device tensor in LibTorch?

Tags: c++, gpu, libtorch

Inside a function called from main(), I am trying to iterate over the elements of a CUDA LibTorch tensor in CPP.

I fail with both `accessor<double, 3>()` and `packed_accessor<double, 3>()`, similarly with `packed_accessor64<double, 3>()`.

The accessor is created fine, but when I try to index any element from the underlying tensor, for example:

```
auto Psi_spec_abs_acc = Psi_spec_abs.packed_accessor<double, 3>();
std::cout << Psi_spec_abs_acc [0][0][0] << std::endl;
```

It fails with segfault.

The code below:

`std::cout << Psi_spec_abs.type() << std::endl;`

produces as output:

```
CUDADoubleType
```

and `Psi_spec_abs` is indeed 3-dimensional.

How could I iterate over a CUDA tensor without putting it into the CPU?

Thank you!

Comment: From the [docs](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/notes/tensor_basics.html#efficient-access-to-tensor-elements) and the [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/0bb2b015414214e8874d4c31188eb2fd883da402/aten/src/ATen/core/TensorAccessor.h), it looks to me as if one needs to copy the tensor (or a slice of it) to the CPU to access it. The reason for this design decision is probably that element-by-element access of a device tensor would generate tons of `cudaMemcpy` calls which is very bad for performance. One way around this might be to use unified memory (`cudaMallocManaged`).